# unique the repeat value of string content

Tags: regex, perl

**Example**
INPUT

> $str= "AAAAATTTTTGGGGGGCCCCCAAAATTTT";

OUTPUT

> ATGCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $s = "AAAAATTTTTGGGGGGCCCCCAAAATTTTAAAGGF";
my @va = $s =~m/(.)\1*/g;
print @va,"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
echo "AAAAATTTTTGGGGGGCCCCCAAAATTTT" | perl -pe 's/(.)\1+/\1/g'
```

`(.)` captures a single character.

`\1+` matches the following same character one or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV6oG0/1)

**or**

```
use warnings;

print "AAAAATTTTTGGGGGGCCCCCAAAATTTT" =~ s/(.)\1+/$1/gr;
```

Comment: +1. But `Non-destructive substitution modifier` not working in before the version of `5.14`. Tells the error something like `Bareword found where operator expected at regex.pl line 2, near "s/(.)\1+/$1/gr"
Can't modify constant item in substitution (s///) at regex.pl line 2, near "s/(.)\1+/$1/gr"` But i learn something from your answer. :)

Comment: @Hussain I don't know about perl but about pcre. I don't find any diff between your regex and mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.)\K\1+
```

You can try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/4

Comment: thanks you @vks.  this regex result can't be assign to a variable. let me know how to do.

Comment: @vks your pattern not unique the character which occurring one time. Example, data like this `$s = "ATGC"` your pattern not give the result. so use the `*` instead of  `+` :)

Comment: @Hussain when its `ATGC` we need to match it.see here https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/5

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print"AAAAATTTTTGGGGGGCCCCCAAAATTTT"=~s/(A|T|G|C)\1*/$1/gr;
```